# Spring Webflow Location Patterns

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am attempting to better understand Spring Webflow's location patterns.

I want to be able to separate the views and flows into their own workflow folders. Those workflow folders could contain multiple flows (most likely in the form of sub-flows).

Here is the default (for my project) configuration for the location pattern:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/jsp">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

I am trying to understand what "/**" means in this pattern...

Using this pattern, I see that any file in "/WEB-INF/jsp" ending with "-flow.xml" is mapped. However, any flows defined in sub-directories are ignored. This is what I want to fix.

I do not want to have to provide a location pattern for every sub-directory generated under /WEB-INF/jsp. I want a pattern that will look at this root (base-path) and also inside all children.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a screen capture of a basic project I'm using to  figure this out:
[image: image of basic project configuration]

Comment: So here is what I have found while messing around... Webflow expects views (JSP pages) to be in /WEB-INF/jsp even if the location-pattern is something like "/WEB-INF/**/*-flow.xml" ....  My goodbye-flow.xml is mapped, but now how I expected. The mapping is to /goodbye, not /goodbye/goodbye-flow.htm as I expected. ... So I can use the folder structure I am wanting with this configuration, but the URLs will be different than what I initially thought. I am not certain I have answered my own question at this point. I want to play around with this template more and figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start your pattern with `/**`:

```
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/jsp">
    <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking. I asked what "/**" stands for and how to configure webflow to find flows in subdirectories.

Comment: I answered how to find subflows

Comment: your code doesn't start with the slash that's why it's not working

Comment: My site was working fine with that configuration; though I did update it anyway. I just didn't understand the mappings generated for the flows in subdirectories. I have a better idea now, but would still like more information on these patterns and how they work. I appreciate your effort and suggestion, but your answer is not for the question I asked.